# Including php variables in CSS (in concrete5)

Tags: php, css, concrete5

I followed this tutorial https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/ to use php variables in CSS. I am using concrete5(version 5.6) CMS. 
I loaded both .php and .css files.

NewFile.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$clRed = 'red';
?>
```

NewFile.css

```
 @import "/path/css/NewFile.php?type=cms";

.one-third{
        width: 33%;
        margin: 0 auto;  
        background: <?php echo $clRed;?>;
    }
```

but css is not reading the php variables.

[image: Chrome Developers tool screenshot]

I also referred these links

http://doctype.com/use-php-variables-inside-css-file

[how can I use of a php variable into a .css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214105/how-can-i-use-of-a-php-variable-into-a-css-file)

[PHP Variables in CSS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181080/php-variables-in-css-not-working)

https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/themes/reusing-editable-values-andor-embedding-php-in-stylesheets

Thanks in advance. 
Note: I know it's not a recommended practice.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot that the css IS an PHP.

Look there:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />
```

Rename NewFile.css to NewFile.css.php and it will work. But I suggest unificate the files, just call NewFile.php as tutorial says. In the head of php file instantiate:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$clRed = 'red';
?>
```

And the rest of the file it's just css with the echos.

Comment: It's not working, what should be the hierarchy.  Should I first import *.css.php file or *.php file?

Comment: Forget the two files, unify them into NewFile.php and put into href of link.

Comment: This works, thank you. For the future readers, this line is very important :-
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");                                                             and another good link - http://jafty.com/blog/tag/php-header-content-type-css/

Comment: Important to remember: It's a bad practice, but fast implementation.

The best case scenario is SASS/LESS or create a CSS generator based into some conf file (can be a PHP file, JSON or INI).

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile php Code in css files.
Your linked tutorial will guide you to create a php script that will put out css code and set the header to "text/css".
So you are able to link your php file as a css stylesheet into a html page.

In your case you have to echo the content of your css file (without the import) in your php file.

style.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$clRed = 'red';

echo '.one-third{
    width: 33%;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    background: '.$clRed.';
}';
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php" />';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first off your error occurs because of the extension you are using is .css not .php. Try this, rename the file extension, then just use the format

```
<style>
.blabla{
....
}

#heeeHoo{
 ...
}
</style>
```

as the user hakiko stated in one of your references, then use 
    `<?php include 'style.php'; ?>` to include it in the desired place. I am fairly certain that PHP `include` just copies and pastes the contents of a file, so [his solution](http://http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214105/how-can-i-use-of-a-php-variable-into-a-css-file) should work. Just make sure to put it in the html `<head>` tag

Comment: Hey, His solution is good but my problem is that my application have 4 sub domains and there will be more subdomains in future, I want to give different color coding to each sub domain, like if a school is logging in the colors should be green and white, when a hospital is using my application then colors should be red and blue. The application already has 15-20 css. It's not possible to change them to .css.php extension so my idea was to create a css.php file and load it after all the the css scripts. In this case using variables will help, I can say if(use=='school') set background = 'red'.

Comment: You can use `!important` to override other uses of the CSS